# Why does the code continue to execute after redirection?

Tags: php, redirect

Why does the execution continue after redirection using `header()`?

```
  $flag=1;

  if($flag==1)
      header("Location:page1.php");

  header("Location:page2.php");
```

When I use this code the browser redirects to `page2.php`.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put an `exit;` after the header call; PHP does not automatically stop executing code after the client stops loading the page.

Answer (score 3):

The code should be like:-

```
$flag=1;
if($flag==1) {
    header("Location:page1.php");
    exit();
}
header("Location:page2.php");
exit();
```

If you don't use the "`exit()`" / "`die()`" construct, PHP will continue to execute the next lines. This is because PHP redirects the user to the first-mentioned page (in this case it's "`page1.php`"), but internally after executing all the statements written in the whole page, even after the "`header()`" method is executed. To stop this, we need to use either the "`exit()`" / "`die()`" constructs.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it works:

Server side: PHP creates a HTML page to send. If `$flag == 1`, it changes its header to `location:page1.php`. In **every case** because there is no `else`, it then changes the header to `location:page2.php`.

**Then**, the page is sent to your **brower**, which redirects you.

My advice: simply put `else` before your second header change.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $flag=1;
  if($flag==1)
  {
      header("Location:page1.php");
      exit();
  }
  header("Location:page2.php");
```

This should prevent redirection to page2.php.
Just remember to put exit() where it's necessary.

Comment: The second `header()` is dead code. You need to put `exit` and first `header` into a `{}` block.

Comment: Please correct the code, as the code which you've written is not correct.